# Shorten regex to capture digits grouped by variable delimiter

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex that is trying to capture integer numbers like

```
12_456_789
```

But the delimiter can by either any of `[\ _.,]` or no delimiter. My regex looks like

```
\d{1,3}((_\d{3})*|(\ \d{3})*|(\.\d{3})*|(,\d{3})*|(\d{3})*)
```

This regex works as epxected, but it's annoying having to repeat myself for each delimiter. I'm tempted to do something like

```
\d{1,3}(([\ _.,]\d{3})*)
```

But this would match a string like

```
123,456.789_987
```

which is not acceptable.

Is there some kind of abbreviation along the lines of my temptation that can be used? Or am I stuck with conjunction repetition?

I'm working in python verbose regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match either 1 or more digits, or 1-3 digits and repeat 1 or more times 3 digits with the same delimiter using a capture group and a backreference.

```
^(?:\d+|\d{1,3}([ _.,])\d{3}(?:\1\d{3})*)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{1,3}` Match 1-3 digits
  - `([ _.,])` Capture **group 1**, match one of the listed characters
  - `\d{3}` Match 3 digits
  - `(?:\1\d{3})*` Optionally repeat matching the same character captured in group 1 using a backreference `\1` followed by matching 3 digits
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mdidt8/1).

Comment: This one is nice. I find it very readable. The only downside is it has to special case the no delimiter case, but that's really not a huge downside since `\d+` covers this case and is one of the simplest regexes around.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to enforce that the delimiter be the same, you could use a capture group as follows:

```
^\d+([\ _.,])?\d*(?:\1\d+)*$
```

### Demo

Explanation of regex pattern:

- `^` from the start of the input

  - `\d+` match an integer
  - `([\ _.,])?` match and capture in `\1` a `[\ _.,]` delimiter
  - `\d*` optional integer
  - `(?:`

    - `\1\d+` then match the same delimiter and another integer
  - `)*` zero or more times
- `$` end of the input

Comment: Ah, nice. I think this is pretty much what I'm looking for. There can be 1, 2, or 3 digits before the first delimiter, and then there are always 3 digits between the other delimiters, so I modified this to `^\d{1,3}(?:([\ _.,])?\d{3})?(\1\d{3})*$`. demo: https://regex101.com/r/M6BUXv/1

Comment: This answer gave me the right idea to use a back reference to a capture group, but it erroneously captures e.g. `12.34.56.78` and `12.`. There may be 1, 2, or 3 digits before the first delimiter, there should always be exactly three digits between each pair of delimiters, and there should always be exactly three digits after the last delimiter. It should also be possible to match any number of digits with no delimiters (e.g. `\d+`).

Comment: You have changed your question after others have already answered.  Not a good thing.

Comment: if I try this RE is will match input  trailing digits that are not a multiple of 3 like: "234_12" or "234_1" is that what the OP was looking for?  oops just saw same comment was already posted while I wrote this!

Comment: My apologies, I didn't change the question, I just wasn't sufficiently clear in the original question I suppose. From looking at the regex in the OP you can see I was looking for three digit groupings

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer using positive look ahead:

```
^\d{1,3}(?:(?:(?=([\ _.,]?))(?:\1\d{3})*))$
```

This has the advantage the string is split into two parts, the part before the first delimiter, and the repeating triplets. The other answers require 3 parts, the part before the first delimiter, the first triplet used to capture the delimiter, then the subsequent repeated triplets.

However, this has the disadvantage that it requires using a lookahead which is a more advanced and possibly confusing regex topic which I didn't understand (and likely beginners don't understand) before writing this answer.

## Demo

Explanation:

- `\d{1,3}` starts out by matching 1, 2, or 3 digits
- We then hit `(?:(?:(?=([\ _.,]?))(?:\1\d{3})*)`
- We begin with a postive lookahead `(?=([\ _.,]?))`. This asserts that this section of the string starts with one of `\` , `_`, `.`, or `,` and captures the delimiter in the only capture group in the regex. The delimiter is not consumed, only read by the lookahead. If the delimiter is not found we capture an empty string
- The next part of the regex is `(?:\1\d{3})*)`. `\1` refers to what was captured in the delimiter capture group and `\d{3}`matches exactly three digits. `*` matches this pattern 0 or more times.

Comment: Not sure if you need a lookahead, also without it seems a bit more efficient and even shorter and better readable: [`^\d{1,3}(?:\d*|([ _.,])\d{3}(?:\1\d{3})*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/uvv4FU/1) (however, your idea is interesting).

Answer (score 1):

you could use a subgroup (parentheses) around the first occurrence of the delimiter and then use a back reference to require that *same* delimiter occur in subsequent locations using the `\n` notation, where *n* is the current level of open parentheses in the RE text

something like this:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"""(?x)   # use eXtended flag to document RE
   ^                  # start at beginning of line
   \d{1,3}            # find 1 to 3 digits
   (([_,.]?)          # find (and remember) valid delimiter (possibly empty string)
    \d{3})?           # followed by exactly 3 digits, 0 or 1 time
   (\2                # find the SAME delimiter (possibly empty string)
    \d{3})*           # followed by exactly 3 digits, 0 or more times
    #(\d{3})?         # find exactly 3 trailing digits, 0 or 1 time    # commented out - see below
   $                  # find the end of the line
""")

# note: as Jagerberg48 pointed out the `(\d{3})?` that was orginally
# not commented out should have been omitted - good catch


while True:
    text = input("> ")
    print("yes" if pattern.search(text) else "no")
```

example input:

```
> 1
yes
> 12
yes
> 123
yes
> 123_
no
> 453_23
no
> 3_32
no
> 32_1
no
> 123_456
yes
> 123_345_384
yes
> 123_452_54
no
> 123_455,039
no
> 123,445,039
yes
> 123.342.444
yes
> 123123
yes
> 12343
yes
> 1234
yes
> 123
yes
> 12
yes
> 1
yes
```

the resulting RE written in normal form is

```
pattern = re.compile("^\d{1,3}(([_,.]?)\d{3})?(\2\d{3})*(\d{3})?$")
```

which is shorter as requested but maybe more importantly avoids the | operator
which can sometimes cause REs to run slower because a higher possibly causing more back tracking the RE matching algorithm

Comment: I don't think the `(\d{3})?` at the end is necessary?

Comment: In fact the `(\d{3})?` at the end is problematic because it allows matching `111.111222`

Comment: There is no need for the second capture group here.  Just use `(?:([_,.]?)\d{3})?`, turn off the outer capture group, and then refer to `\1` later in the pattern.

Comment: Yes, this can be updated to `^\d{1,3}(?:([\ _,.]?)\d{3})?(\1\d{3})*$` I think

Comment: yes true, I lazily used capturing parens ( ) when I didn't need them, as Jaberber48 points out the intent of the first paran being non capturing is better unambigously written as with the non-capturing parens syntax `(?:    )`

Comment: Doh!  Yes Jagerber48 is correct the trailing `(\d{3})?` is unnecessary and problematic, accidentally included from a previous attempt - good catch!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I always wonder about the trade off between technical correctness (and improved performance) of using non-capturing `(?:...)` where possible with the increased brevity/readability of `(...)`. It sounds like you are in favor of the technically correct `(?:...)` where possible which is a helpful data point for me

Comment: In this case, referring to a `\2` without a `\1` is confusing IMHO, because then it is not clear why you have 2 capture groups.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen agreed. If you liberally use `(...)` for visual brevity you run into trouble exactly in back-reference cases where you're now going to have a harder time figure out which number the group is. In python you could used named capture groups to help with this and be more explicit. But for this case I agree `(?:...)` and `\1` is easy.

Comment: @quizdog you can edit this answer to remove the trailing `(\d{3})?` and add the `111.111222 test case.